# Scala streaming a live/growing file

Tags: scala, akka, streaming, akka-stream, akka-actor

My Scala application kicks off an external process that writes a file to disk. In a separate thread, I want to read that file and copy its contents to an `OutputStream` until the process is done and the file is no longer growing.

There are a couple of edge cases to consider:

1. The file may not exist yet when the thread is ready to start.
2. The thread may copy faster than the process is writing. In other words, it may reach the end of the file while the file is still growing.

BTW I can pass the thread a `processCompletionFuture` variable which indicates when the file is done growing.

**Is there an elegant and efficient way to do this? Perhaps using Akka Streams or actors?** (I've tried using an Akka Stream off of the `FileInputStream`, but the stream seems to terminate as soon as there are no more bytes in the input stream, which happens in case #2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpakka, a library that is built on Akka Streams, has a [`FileTailSource`](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/alpakka/0.18/akka/stream/alpakka/file/scaladsl/FileTailSource$.html) utility that mimics the `tail -f` Unix command. For example:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl._
import akka.util.{ ByteString, Timeout }
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.nio.file.Path
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val path: Path = ???

val maxLineSize = 10000

val tailSource: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = FileTailSource(
  path = path,
  maxChunkSize = maxLineSize,
  startingPosition = 0,
  pollingInterval = 500.millis
).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), maxLineSize, true))
```

The above `tailSource` reads an entire file line-by-line and continually reads freshly appended data every 500 milliseconds. To copy the stream contents to an `OutputStream`, connect the source to a [`StreamConverters.fromOutputStream`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.12/akka/stream/scaladsl/StreamConverters$.html#fromOutputStream(out:()=%3Ejava.io.OutputStream,autoFlush:Boolean):akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[akka.util.ByteString,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.stream.IOResult]]) sink:

```
val stream: Future[IOResult] =
  tailSource
    .runWith(StreamConverters.fromOutputStream(() => new OutputStream {
      override def write(i: Int): Unit = ???
      override def write(bytes: Array[Byte]): Unit = ???
    }))
```

(Note that there is a `FileTailSource.lines` method that produces a `Source[String, NotUsed]`, but in this scenario it's more felicitous to work with `ByteString` instead of `String`. This is why the example uses `FileTailSource.apply()`, which produces a `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`.)

The stream will fail if the file doesn't exist at the time of materialization. Therefore, you'll need to confirm the existence of the file before running the stream. This might be overkill, but one idea is to use Alpakka's [`DirectoryChangesSource`](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/alpakka/0.18/akka/stream/alpakka/file/scaladsl/DirectoryChangesSource$.html) for that.

Comment: Looks promising, but here are some problems I run into with this:

  1. I can't seem to chain `DirectoryChangesSource` with `FileTailSource`, as both are `Source`s, and also I'd want to terminate the former as soon as it sees the file created

  2. `FileTailSource` needs to terminate when `processCompletionFuture` is completed (and we must make sure to do a final copy of bytes after the completion).

Sorry if there are obvious solutions to this, but I'm new to akka streams.